# Как выбрать уникальные значения (представлены в виде списков) ключей и отправить на печать в алфавитном порядке Python

Tags: python

У меня есть словарь

```
dict = {
    'a': ['Andrew', 'Albert', 'Mike'], 
    'b': ['Mike', 'Billy', 'John'],
    'c': ['Eric', 'Albert', 'Frank']
}
```

Вопрос - как можно вытащить все уникальные значения и отправить их на печать в виде:
'Albert, Andrew, Billy, Eric, Frank, John, Mike'

Я пробовал сгенерировать строку

```
list = ','.join(dict[key].pop(0) for key in sorted(dict))
```

но не смог убрать дублирование

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_list = ', '.join(sorted(set(sum(my_dict.values(),start=[]))))
```

`sorted` - сортировка нужна в конце

`set` - список без дублей

`sum` - один из способов сцепить списки в один

`my_dict.values` - достает значения из словаря

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: `set` - это не просто "список без дублей" - это множество.

Comment: @Student_Py, если вам помог этот ответ, отметьте его как "принятый" (серая галочка слева).

Comment: множество это список без дублей и без сортировки)

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте слова 'dict' и 'list' в качестве названия переменных, это помешает в случае, если вам нужно будет обратиться к функции `dict()` или `list()`.

А сделать это можно примерно так:

```
my_dict = {
    'a': ['Andrew', 'Albert', 'Mike'], 
    'b': ['Mike', 'Billy', 'John'],
    'c': ['Eric', 'Albert', 'Frank']
}

unique_values = set()
for lst in my_dict.values():
    unique_values.update(lst)

result = ', '.join(unique_values)
print(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!